# IntelliJ ultimate 2017 SQL syntax highlighting

Tags: intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ 2017.3 Ultimate and I would like to turn on `SQL` syntax highlighting. I have tried:

- `File` -> `Settings` -> `Languages and frameworks` -> `Template Data Languges` -> `<plus>` -> `<mark sql directory>` -> Languge to `MySQL` -> `apply`
- `File` -> `Settings` -> `Languages and frameworks` -> `SQL Dialects` -> `Global/Project SQL Dialect` and `<plus>` to point to the sql directory.

It still doesn't highlight syntax error f.e. `FRGN KEY` isn't underscored as error.

Where exactly I can mark directory as a folder that holds `MySQL` files ?

Comment: Where do you want to enable highlighting? In String literal in Java code (see [how you can inject a language in string](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-injected-sql-statements.html)) or in sql file (see [editing sql files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-and-editing-sql-files.html))?

Comment: "in sql file (see editing sql files)". I went through: "Specifying an SQL dialect". When I changed `CONSTRAINT` to `CONSTRAINTabc` it is not highlighted red, should be ? And when I have correct syntax like `CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT);` it highlight `TABLE` (in red) and when I hover over it, it says: `expected one of the following: ALGORITHM DEFINER SQL VIEW `